# Want to get previous date from current date

Tags: date, vbscript

i have problem finding solution on getting previous date from current's date. but i only want the months to change. for example, now is August, i want the output to display 3 months ago = May. 
Heres my code that i wrote

```
givenDate= "14-August-15"

DD = Day (givenDate)
'MsgBox DD

MM = Month (givenDate)
'MsgBox MM

YY = Year (givenDate)
'MsgBox YY 

SysDate = DD&"/"&MM&"/"&YY

MsgBox Month(DateAdd("m", -3, "14-August-2015"))
'MsgBox(FormatDateTime(SysDate,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to display the name of the month that was 3 months ago, combine `DateAdd()`, `Month()`, and `MonthName()`. For example:

```
Dim dt1, dt2
dt1 = Date()                        ' Use today's date, for example
dt2 = DateAdd("m", -3, dt1)         ' Subtract 3 months

WScript.Echo MonthName(Month(dt2))  ' Display the name of the month
```

`Month()` returns the month number (`1 - 12`). `MonthName()` takes that number and returns the name of the month (`"January" - "December"`).

Comment: What if i want to display the full date? example : 1. Changing your shoft date to long date. E.g. resulting date would be 17-Aug-15, 17 –August-2015

Comment: I'm not displaying a short date. I'm displaying the month, because that's what you asked for. If you want to create custom date formats, extract the date components using `Month()`, `Day()`, `Year()` and piece them back together yourself or use a .Net library. For example: `WScript.Echo CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder").AppendFormat("{0:dd-MMMM-yyyy}", Date).ToString()`.