# How to get yesterday's date vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Date format Shows Invalid Date With Custom Date. When I use 'Date' instead of "25th May" it shows yesterday's Date.

```
function GetYD()
    Dim dt, yesterday

    dt = DateAdd("d", -1, "25th May")

     yesterday = Right(Year(dt),2) & Right("0" & Month(dt),2) & Right("0" & Day(dt),2)
     msgbox yesterday
    GetYD = yesterday
end function
```

Comment: Did you read the [`DateAdd()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb7z8yf9(v=vs.84).aspx)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to get previous date from current date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053267/want-to-get-previous-date-from-current-date)

Comment: Also recommend [CDate Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dt118h2(v=vs.84).aspx) to understand how `Date` types in VBScript are structured.

Comment: Thanks! Guys, I have checked out the documentation and the problem was the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to feed it a string that can be parsed. Always use digits if possible, and you did not even specify a year.

The format `yyyy-mm-dd` would probably work best, as it is (both to humans and to computers) totally un-ambiguous. So try it using

```
DateAdd("d", -1, "2017-05-25")
```